Birthday probability similar to birthday paradox
I am having a party with 20 guests and I want to find the probability to share my birthday with exactly one of the guests (depending on the result, I may buy a second birthday cake, just in case!!).
I know how to calculate the probability for at least one of the guests: The probability for everyone of the 20 guests to have their birthdays on any other date is $364/365$, therefore for all of them it's $\frac{364}{365}^{20}$. To find the probability for at least one of the guests to have the same birthday as me, we get the complementary probability:
$P = 1 - \frac{364}{365}^{20}$.
I am not sure about the "exactly one".
Should we calculate the ways to form pairs with each of the guests? Then we will have one pair and 19 guests with different birthdays, that is, the first pair (me and one of the guests, say the 1st) will share a birthday and then the 2nd guest will have 364 possible dates, the 3rd 363 and so on.
Edit: I realized that there is some confusion regarding the interpretation of my question, so I will try to clarify (apologies, English is not my mother tongue, so maybe I did not express it properly).
I am looking for the probability to have the same birthday with one (=not one in particular, could be anyone) of my guests. That's why I wrote the "joke" about the second birthday cake. It has to be only one, not "at least" one. Also, I am not interested about the other guests, as long as they don't have birthday the same date as me (and the other guest). Other than that, they have groups of the same birthday, but not with me. Hope it is clear now.

So it's 20 guests plus you, right?

There seems to be some confusion about exactly what the question is. Do you want the probability that exactly one of your guests shares your birthday, and none of the others do? Or is it important that the guests each have different birthdays?

We assume that you have a fixed birthday:

The total number of outcomes: there are 20 guests with 365 possible birthdays for each. So in total we have $365^{20}$ outcomes.
The number of favorable outcomes: if a guest $x$ has the same birthday, there are 364 possible birthdays for each of remaining 19 guests which gives $364^{19}$. Since we have 20 guests, we multiply it by 20 which gives $20 \cdot 364^{19}$

By the naive definition of probability we have
$$P = \frac{20 \cdot 364^{19}}{365^{20}}$$
We can get the same result by using Binomial(20, 1/365):
$$P(X=1) = \begin{pmatrix}20 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}  \left(\frac{1}{365}\right)^{1}\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{19}$$

Also of note, $\mathbb P(X=1) \approx 0.052$ while $\mathbb P(X\ge 1)\approx 0.0534$. Therefore, conditionally on $X\ge 1$, the event $X=1$ dominates the other ones. This is not unexpected. By Poisson approximation, $X$ is roughly Poisson distributed with parameter $\frac{20}{365}$, so the tail is very thin, and because of the low parameter, $X=2$ is already a tail event.

"I am having a party with $20$ guests" is clear that I am there + $20$ others
Any of the $20$ may share my birthday, and all else must have a different one, (please read the full question!) thus
$Pr = \dfrac{\binom{20}1\cdot 365^\underline{20}}{365^{21}}$
where $365^\underline{20}$ is the falling factorial $365\cdot364\cdot363...$ with $20$ terms

$\mathbf{Added}$
A controversy on interpreting the question has arisen, so I am adding an analysis for the interpretation where I share a birthday with exactly one guest, and don't care whether others share birthdays or not.
Then $Pr= \dfrac{\binom{20}1\cdot365\cdot364^{19}}{365^{21}}$
As can be seen, my sharing a birthday with exactly one guest, and not botheing about other guests sharing birthdays or not, is higher than if just I and one guest share a birthday.

I disagree and I think that the answer is much simpler : "..I want to find the probability to share my birthday with exactly one of the guests...".  This means that after one guest is chosen, whose birthday will match the party host, the other 19 guests must each have a birthday that does not match the party host.  This implies that the other 19 guests are free to have birthdays that match themselves.  For example, if the host has a birthday on Jan 1, a satisfactory outcome is one of the 20 guests also having a birthday on Jan 1, and all of the other 19 guests having a birthday on Jan 2.

Yes, why are you using the falling factorial? There is no stipulation that the guests themselves have distinct birthdays.

I should also indicate that one might argue that the answer of true blue anil is correct, and that the original poster simply mis-stated the question that they wish to pose.  While I don't think that this is a reasonable interpretation of the stated question, it is backed up by the evidence of the analysis attempted by the original poster, as shown in the last paragraph of their posted question.

@user2661923: Exactly  ! On reading the full question, it is evident that OP wants to compute the probability that one of the guests has a matching birthday with her/him, and the remaining have distinct birthdays.

Here, I disagree.  I actually think that it is somewhat more plausible that the original poster correctly presented the question that they wish to pose, and then made an analytical error.  However, the viewpoint in your last comment can not be conclusively eliminated.

@ChrisLewis: Pl. read the entire question, not just the first line. It is quite clear what OP is asking for, although it could have been put more clearly.

I suggest adding a second half to your answer, where you provide analysis/computation for the viewpoint that the intended question is : "..I want to find the probability to share my birthday with exactly one of the guests...".

The question appears to about the distinction between calculations for "exactly one" and "at least one". The part where guests having distinct birthdays comes up is in the attempted solution. It's pretty clear that you don't require the guests to each have distinct birthdays if you're wondering about how many cakes you want to buy, but I've asked OP to clarify; it's their question, after all, and at least two people here interpreted it differently to you.

I see you've now edited your answer, but seem to have a typo where you say $\binom{10}1$. Bearing in mind OP's question isn't worded very mathematically, you might want to actually explain what these answers actually mean.

@ChrisLewis: Anyway, since differing interpretations are there, I have added the computation for the alternate interpretation, too, as suggested by user2661923 Correctef the typo, too,thanks.

To all: I made an edit to clarify some grey areas. However, I think that @user2661923 has correctly interpreted the question. Thank you all for your solutions and comments so far.

Good point; I missed that.
